# Change between Qt4 and Qt5 with conflicting access keys and Shortcut keys

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, qt5

There is a change between QT4 and QT5 when handling Menubar menus access keys and QActions shortcuts that have conflicting key combinations.

In Qt4 when a MenuBar contains a menu with an ampersand like &File it can be opened by tapping on Alt and then tapping F.  If a QAction is created using the same hotkey combination like Alt+F then the QAction ‘s signal will be fired if Alt and F are pushed simultaneously or alt is held down and F is pushed.
This is similar functionality to Visual Studios and other MS programs.

In Qt5.4 and Qt5.5 when a MenuBar contains a menu with an ampersand like &File it can be opened by tapping on Alt and then tapping F. If a QAction is created using the same hotkey combination like Alt+F then the QAction ‘s signal will be NOT fired.  Instead nothing happens and a warning message is sent to the application output.

QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Alt+F

This issue can be duplicated using a QTcreator example like menus and changing the setshortcut for newAct to Alt+F or another shortkey that is the same as a menubar.

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
fileMenu->addAction(newAct);

void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
    newAct->setShortcut(tr("Alt+F"));  // This will work in QT4 but not in QT5 and will send a message QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Alt+F
    newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
    connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));
```

My question is what is the correct functionality for windows QT4 or Qt5.  If QT5 is correct is there a way to setup Qt so it acts like QT4 instead.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Don't hate your users. Don't do that.

Application-global key shortcuts must be unambiguous. Qt5's behavior is correct. Qt4 failed to detect this, and would let you horribly mislead the user. When a user sees an underline keyboard shortcut for the menu or a menu item, they have every right to believe that the shortcut is application global and won't depend on the context. What you observed in Qt 4 was "allowed", but very bad from usability perspective and had no place in polished, professional applications.

To get the behavior you're after, you must make the action unambiguous: you must remove the shortcut from the menu action. That will work correctly: the menu loses the shortcut, and your application-global shortcut takes over that key sequence.

Alas, I'm very much doubtful that it is a good idea to take over a *very* common menu shortcut - one that is present in most Windows applications that have menus. If I was your user, I would *not* like you for taking over Alt-F.

Comment: "To get the behavior you're after, you must make the action unambiguous: you must remove the shortcut from the menu action. That will work correctly: the menu loses the shortcut, and your application-global shortcut takes over that key sequence."

The menu action is not a shortcut it's a mnemonic access key.  See this MSDN doc for the difference between access keys and shortcut keys.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The QT4 behavior is allowed in other MS application like Visual Studios.  If you set for example File.OpenfromSourceControl to Alt+F and then hold down alt and push F File.OpenfromSourceControl will work.  If you tap alt and hit F the file menu will be selected and open.  This is the same functionality as QT4.
In QT5 if you tap alt and hit F the file menu will be selected and open, this is correct.  If you hold down alt and hit F you get an Ambiguous short overload, this functionality is not correct and doesn't match other MS windows programs.

Comment: @DonaldHerman You do need to manually remove the mnemonic from the menu if you wish to use the shortcut. That's all. You'll get Qt4's behavior as seen by the user.